# matplotlib legend to scatter

Tags: matplotlib, legend, scatter, legend-properties

I am using the scatter method of matplot lib to present 9 types of shape   combinations with the following code

```
for idx in combinedArray:
        line = self.container.axes.scatter(
            self.reducedDimentions[combinedArray == idx, 0],
            self.reducedDimentions[combinedArray == idx, 1],
            color=colors[int(idx / 3)],
            marker=markers[int(idx % 3)],
            label = str(idx))
```

The result is :
[image]

I want to add legend so I added the following code

```
for idx in combinedArray:
        line = self.container.axes.scatter(
            self.reducedDimentions[combinedArray == idx, 0],
            self.reducedDimentions[combinedArray == idx, 1],
            color=colors[int(idx / 3)],
            marker=markers[int(idx % 3)],
            label = str(idx))
        lines.append(line)
        texts.append(str(idx))
    self.container.axes.legend(lines, texts,
       scatterpoints=1,
       loc='lower left',
       ncol=3,
       fontsize=8)
    self.container.draw()
```

And the result was :
[image]

Can you tell me why and how to fix it ?
Thanks,
Ilan

Comment: Could you please create a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: I created such an example and found my error